# Drupal 8 - Alter session variable without redirecting the page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm looking for a solution to change a Drupal Session Variable (`PrivateTempStoreFactory`) without redirecting to another page. I can accomplish altering the variable by using routing.yml in my module, but this is not a solution that is effective as it changes to a different path.

Simply put, I am trying to create a `Role` menu in which a `User` can select an available role that has been assigned to them. When they select a role, their role should be updated in the session and redirected back to the page they started the action (`Menu` and other things may change, hence the page needs to be reloaded).

Any help would be appreciated! I'm learning Drupal 8 and it's been quite the curve!

Comment: I have to alter a server-side variable, through the Drupal framework. A simple JavaScript solution would not solve my issue. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up utilizing the Drupal [Ajax API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x) where the callback would use a location.reload(). Problem Solved